# SVG Filter: Only working in Chrome, not other browsers

Tags: javascript, svg, filter, cross-browser, svg-filters

Simple demo of bug here: https://codepen.io/mknepprath/pen/mKeObo

Open in Chrome to see how it should look.

Issues:

- In Safari, the filter seems to not apply or only apply partially...
  it's different.
- In Firefox, nothing shows up at all - it seems to
  hide the filter and the div that the filter is applied to.

How do I get this to work consistently across browsers?

html:

```
<svg class='a'>
  <defs>
    <filter id='hey'>
      <feColorMatrix
        type='matrix'
        result='darken'
        x='0'
        y='0'
        width='200px'
        height='100px'
        values='.2 .05  .05 0 .35
                .05 .2  .05 0 .35
                .05 .05 .2  0 .35
                0   0    0  1 0'
      />
      <feColorMatrix
        type='matrix'
        result='node'
        x='0'
        y='0'
        width='200px'
        height='100px'
        values='1 0 0 0 0
                0 1 0 0 0
                0 0 1 0 0
                0 0 0 1 0'
      />
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in='darken' />
        <feMergeNode in='node' />
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div class='b' style='filter: url(#hey)'></div>
```

css:

```
.a {
  display: none;
}

.b {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: peachpuff;
}
```

Comment: and without the display:none?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome accepts bad syntax and tries to make the best of it, Firefox generally does not.

- Using display:none takes the SVG out of the DOM so the CSS can't find the style anymore. Make the SVG zero sized, put it below your content or use visbility: hidden
- In SVG 1.1 at least, you shouldn't' be able to use "px", "em" etc. to dimension your filter elements. (And there should be no need to size your feColorMatrixes - sizes are autocalculated by default.)

```css
.a {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.b {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: peachpuff;
}
```

```html
<svg class="a">
  <defs>
    <filter id="hey">
      <feColorMatrix
        type="matrix"
        result="darken"
        values=".2 .05  .05 0 .35
                .05 .2  .05 0 .35
                .05 .05 .2  0 .35
                0   0    0  1 0"
      />
      <feColorMatrix
        type="matrix"
        result="node"
        values="1 0 0 0 0
                0 1 0 0 0
                0 0 1 0 0
                0 0 0 1 0"
      />
      <feMerge>
        <feMergeNode in="darken" />
        <feMergeNode in="node" />
      </feMerge>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div class="b" style="filter: url(#hey)"></div>
```